# Is Addis Ababa safe if I only stay inside the airport for a couple of hours?

Tags: ethiopian-airlines, add

I have a flight from India to Israel via Addis Ababa with a layover for 8 h 15 mn. I have two questions:

1. Are Indians allowed to stay there for 8 h 15 mn without a transit visa?
2. Am I safe there if I don't go outside of the airport?

Comment: I have not been there for a while but when I did go you had to have a flight reservation even to go inside the airport buildings so I imagine you will be as safe there as anywhere.

Comment: Airports in general a lot safer then other places. And considering that Addis Abeba has many international connections, we can be sure that the standards are enough high:L many countries have requirements on safety of departing airport (and also they may do or delegate random audits on airport security)

Comment: Airports tend to be heavily policed and access is tightly controlled. Exactly what are you worried about? Pickpockets? Luggage theft? Robbery/mugging? Terrorism? War?

Comment: If war makes the airport unsafe, airlines will be the first to cancel flights to and from there.  Note how Ukrainian airspace has been closed since March 2022 and Gazan airspace since 2001.

Comment: You can get free transit visa and hotel stay with Ethiopian Airlines. Lots of Indians take advantage of that to explore the city. What do you mean by "safe"? https://www.ethiopianairlines.com/aa/services/services-at-the-airport/addis-ababa-stopovers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Regardless of nationality, transit visas are **not required** for transits under 12 hours at Addis Ababa Bole airport.
2. The airport is heavily policed, so **you'll be fine**. If anything, in terms of crime rate, [Addis Ababa itself is safer than most large Indian cities](https://www.numbeo.com/crime/compare_cities.jsp?country1=India&city1=Delhi&country2=Ethiopia&city2=Addis%20Ababa).